# Use of Boolean Logic: And/Or And True/False

Tags: python, boolean

I'm learning basic Boolean logic with Python. I understand the equality operators but get confused when ands and ors get thrown in. Take a look at the following code for example:

```
people = 20
cats = 30
dogs = 15

if people < cats:
   print "too many cats! the world is doomed!"

if people == cats or dogs == cats:
   print "this is too hard"
```

I understand the first if statement and why it prints. i don't know how the second if statement is evaluated. How could I change it to get that line to print?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It means exactly what it says: it prints if `people == cats` or if `dogs == cats`. Neither of these is the case right now: `people` is 20 and `cats` is 30, and 20 is not equal to 30. `dogs` is 15, and 15 is not equal to 30. I don't understand how there's anything not to understand here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`and` requires that ***all*** of its parts in the expression evaluate to `True` for the whole expression to be `True`.

`or` is much less picky, as soon as ***any*** part of the expression evaluates to `True` the whole expression is `True`.

You may come across the term **short-circuiting** in this context. It simply means that we stop evaluating expressions as soon as we can determine its outcome.

So for an `and` we can stop looking at the rest of the expression as soon as we find a part that evaluates to `False` because at that point the expression can never evaluate to `True`.

Likewise, with `or`, as soon as we find a part that's `True`, we know the whole expression will be `True` and there won't be a reason to look further.

For the code example you posted:

```
if people == cats or dogs == cats:
    print "this is too hard"
```

if either one of these, or both of  `people == cats`, `dogs == cats` evaluated to `True`, the whole expression in the `if` statement would become `True`. Since *neither* of them are `True`, the expression in the `if` statement fails, i.e., is `False`, and the print statement is not executed.

Finally, if you wanted to print statement to execute, you'd have to ensure that the Boolean expression evaluated to `True`. One way would be to change to value of
`dogs` to `30` because then `dogs == cats` would be `True` and that would be
sufficient to make the whole expression `True` and get the print to execute.

Comment: thanks for this explanation. so, will the statement print only if the if statement is true?

Comment: Yes. Also, note that in your example, *neither* of the statements is true. ( 20 != 30 != 15 ) With your values, you could get this line to run using "if not ( people == cats ) or ( dogs == cats ):"... in that form, your if block would only evaluate if one or both conditions weren''t met.

Comment: @VarunShetty Yes, that's right. The `if` really works like we intuitively think of it. I.e., "if this is the case (ie true) then some action". Since the Boolean expression in the if evaluated to False, the body of the if-statement (in the case the print) would not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

OR tests if both or one statement is true, AND tests if both statements are true.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statements are both evaluated the same way.

```
if something:
    do_stuff
```

If `something` is True, then the `do_stuff` block is run[1]. If `something` is not True then the `do_stuff` block is not run. The difference between your two if statements is not that one "works differently" than the other, but that they are run on different versions of `something`.

`and` and `or` are binary operations that take truth values and compute new truth values. Much as in `1 + 3` the `+` is a binary operation that takes the numbers `1` and `3` and produces a new number `4`. `a and b` takes the two truth values `a` and `b` and produces a new one. And much as we can have either `x + y` or `x * y` that produce different numbers from the numbers `x` and `y`, we can have `a and b` or `a or b`, which produce different truth values from the truth values `a` and `b`.

But the `if` statement doesn't care about that. It doesn't need to know **how** we got the truth value it's testing, it will work exactly the same either way. `and` and `or` are entirely separate, they're just ways of combining truth values to get new ones.

---

The intuition for how `and` and `or` work is based on some ways that we use `and` and `or` in English when talking about things that can be either true or false.

In the statement "If *it is raining* then I will get an umbrella", the "it is raining" part is a condition that could be either true or false, and the rest of the sentence is saying what will happen if it's true. In English I could also say "If *it is raining* **and** *I feel like walking* then I will get an umbrella"; this has the two separate conditions "it is raining" and "I feel like walking" combined into one condition by the word **and**. This sentence means I will get an umbrella if both "it is raining" and "I feel like walking" are true; if it's sunny then I don't think I need an umbrella, and if I'm driving then I don't care about getting wet between my house and the car.

I could also have said "If *it is raining* **or** *I feel like walking* then I will get an umbrella". This sentence means that I will get an umbrella if either one or both of the conditions are true. Here we could guess that if it's raining I want to have an umbrella for later in the day even if I don't feel like walking, and if I feel like walking I want to have an umbrella in case it rains later during my walk, even if it's not raining now.

The best way to understand truth values in programming and the `and` and `or` operators is to keep this natural understanding of English `and` and `or` in mind. This gives you an intuitive way of quickly understanding simple expressions involving `and` and `or`. But in programming the way `and` and `or` works is formalised, so we can write down *exactly* how they work, regardless of any ambiguities or special cases in normal English usage.

`A and B` is True if `A` is True and `B` is True, and False otherwise (it is False if either `A` or `B` is False). `A or B` is is True if either `A` or `B` is True (it is False if `A` is False and `B` is False, and True otherwise). Here's a table that shows this:

```
  A   |   B   |  A and B
------+-------+---------
True  | True  |   True
True  | False |   False
False | True  |   False
False | False |   False

  A   |   B   |  A or B
------+-------+--------
True  | True  |   True
True  | False |   True
False | True  |   True
False | False |   False
```

---

[1] In fact, the story is a little more complicated than this (as is true for my whole answer). Most boolean operations in Python (including the `if` statement and the operators `and` and `or`) operate not on exact Truth values, but on "truthy" values. Briefly numbers that are 0, empty containers and strings, and the special value `None` act as if they were `False` when you give them to operations that expect truth values, and everything else acts as if they were `True`. We sometimes use the terms "truthy" or "falsey" to describe values that are not necessarily `True` or `False` but are acting as if they were.

Likewise, operations that produce new truth values from existing ones, like `and` and `or` do not necessarily return `True` or `False`, they might return a value you gave them that is "truthy" or "falsey" as required by the tables above.

But, if someone reading this is at an early stage in learning to program with truth values, I would **strongly** recommend you ignore this and just think of yourself as manipulating `True` and `False`, and likewise don't worry about "short-circuit evaluation" and the order in which things are checked (it doesn't matter if only genuine `True` and `False` are involved, or even most of the time when you're using other values). It's pretty easy to stretch your understanding to these concepts once you have the fundamentals down.